# Argument of type 'typeof Environment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Environment'

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
enum Environment {
    Production = 'production',
    Development = 'development',
    Test = 'test'
}

export class Config {
    public constructor(EnvProd: Environment = Environment.Production, EnvEnum = Environment) {
        Config.createConsoleLog(EnvProd, EnvEnum, console);
    }

    private static createConsoleLog(EnvProd: Environment, EnvEnum: Environment, console: Console): void {
        console.log(EnvProd, EnvEnum);
    }
}
```

Gets the error:

```
karlm@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~/dev/sg$ npx ts-node application/libs/config/index.ts 
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
application/libs/config/index.ts:9:42 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Environment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Environment'.

9         Config.createConsoleLog(EnvProd, EnvEnum, console);
                                           ~~~~~~~
```

Been trying to figure out why I can't get this to work.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Currently you're sending the whole enum object where enum value expected, hence the error

Comment: If you want to allow passing the "enum object" for whatever reason, the signature should be `createConsoleLog(EnvProd: Environment, EnvEnum: typeof Environment, console: Console): void`

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ahhh I see! Post an answer and I'll accept gladly!

Comment: Could you share what's the use case? (just curious)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Rewriting some stuff into pure functions, so everything needs to go through arguments, also introducing default parameters! Nothing more than that! Not very used to TypeScript as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're sending the whole enum object where enum value expected, hence the error.

If you want to allow passing the "enum object" the signature should be:

```
private static createConsoleLog(EnvProd: Environment, EnvEnum: typeof Environment, console: Console): void
```

Pay attention to `typeof Environment` (enum object is also value)